# New connect Instagram feature using Instagram graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

My requirement is to add the feature of Instagram connect and fetch their post/medias.

So I am referring this link [Instagram APIs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) for Instagram connect feature in my android app to fetch user posts of Instagram. as written in document Instagram developer APIs are going to deprecated in early 2020. so I read this new link [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) of Instagram graph APIs.

**So the problem is I am uncleared with the flow of connect Instagram feature using graph APIs**.
So below are my queries:

- If I need to connect Instagram and want to fetch their post/media

  1. Do we need to authenticate with Instagram or Facebook?
  2. What will be the flow of it for the user experience?
  3. And all the user that want to connect with Instagram. they have to create Facebook page and link Instagram account to Facebook page?
  4. Or we only need to configure developer account with these steps [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/#connect)

Thanks
Happy Coding....

Answer (score 4):

The "old" Instagram API is going to be deprecated soon. You should use Facebook Graph API instead. However you need to keep in mind that at the moment Facebook Graph API supports only Instagram Business Accounts. It is not possible to fetch Instagram posts for "regular" Instagram accounts. If you need to support both, you have to apply for both APIs - Instagram API and Facebook Graph API.

1. With old API you need to authenticate via Instagram login flow. With new Graph API you need to go via Facebook login.
2. User needs to connect his/her account to your app. Depends on API you are planning to use, but user will have to go either through Instagram (regular accounts) or Facebook (business accounts) and approve access for your app to their content.
3. Yes, if you plan to use Facebook and Graph API. The requirement for Instagram Business Account is to have Facebook page connected to Instagram account. It is not required for regular accounts and Instagram old API. However you can also access business accounts from old API too;)
4. It really depends on your use-case. If this is only internal app and you plan to support your personal Instagram account, you cna basically configure the developer account only. But if you plan to release the app to global account you need to go through verification process and app review on Facebook.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Insta Graph API as well, but confused on if I need to submit my app for review first because I don't have an app yet! Any advice?